# Layout Issues with Browsers on IPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am trying to fix some layout issues with browsers on tablets. And currently the browsers on surface and Android works okay, but there are some problems with Ipad.
This the main page displayed by an Android Tablet browser:

[image: android view]

And this is the main page displayed by Ipad (safari and chrome)

[image: iPad view]

The webpage is using bootstrap and the URL is http://hra.case.edu.

Here is my meta tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Also I set a `min-width=100%` to the header div, but it seems to be useless in a certain page on iPad, please see this image:

[image: iPad 2]

Anyone has some ideas about those problems?

Comment: Thx Paul for attaching the images!! I just dont have that many credits to post the images...